# Case insensitive sorting doesn't work for non ascii characters

Tags: sort, ascii

Make a list of these words:

```
Če
Čeprav
Človeški
čaka
čakal
čakalne
čakati
časih
časovni
času
če
```

Select all: `ggVG` and sort them with case insensitive: `:sort i`

```
Če
Čeprav
Človeški
čaka
čakal
čakalne
čakati
časih
časovni
času
če
```

You may have already detected a problem... But let's compare it with lowering case and then sorting them:

First, convert it to lower case: `ggVGgu`. and then sort them: `:sort`. You get:

```
čaka
čakal
čakalne
čakati
časih
časovni
času
če
če <-- DIFFERENCE
čeprav <-- DIFFERENCE
človeški <-- DIFFERENCE
```

I was expecting no differences between the 2 methods, so I don't get why I have this inconsistency?

Comment: you might want to use `sort l` to use the current locale for sorting.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. I don't get why this isn't by default?

Comment: I tried `:sort l` and it didn't seem to help... I checked `:echo v:collate` and it always seems to give me `C`. Using `:lang collate en_US` didn't work either. I'm wondering if this is a multi-language feature I'm missing in the builds I'm trying...

Comment: @filbranden Try `:lang collate sl_SI`.

Comment: @ThePhi please post an answer with what worked for you! Thanks!

Comment: Oh and welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: The answer is @christian-brabandt's comment here. He can post his answer and I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vim release [8.2.0988](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/v8.2.0988), Vim supports sorting by the collation. That means, it uses your currently configured locale (`$LC_COLLATE`). Using the collation order also means, there are specific rules for sorting multi-byte characters for your configured locale.

If it is set, you can see by the output of `:lang` or using `:echo v:collate`.

So by setting your locale correctly you can sort using the `:sort l` parameter. Usually, sorting by the collation is also case insensitive, although that does not always have to be.